# Struggling with the logic for a tip tax calculator with specific needs (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program for school with the following parameters:

Write a program that will calculate a XXX% tip and a 6% tax on a meal price.  The user will enter the meal price and the program will calculate tip, tax, and the total.  The total is the meal price plus the tip plus the tax.  Your program will then display the values of tip, tax, and total.

The restaurant now wants to change the program so that the tip percent is based on the meal price.  The new amounts are as follows:

```
Meal Price Range       Tip Percent
.01 to 5.99            10%
6 to 12.00             13%
12.01 to 17.00         16%
17.01 to 25.00         19%
25.01 and more         22%
```

Here is my code so far:

def main():

```
#variables for calculating tip

a = .10
b = .13
c = .16
d = .19
e = .22

#variable for calculating tax

tax = .06

#variable for user input

user = 0.0
total = 0.0

#get user input

user = float(input("Please input the cost of the meal "))

if user > .01 and user < 5.99:
```

From here I have been unsuccessful in taking the user input and making my calculation of user*tax+user = total. That should give me my calculation but how do I implement it. This is on Python 3.6 IDLE.

Comment: It's pretty much the same as the first program, except now instead of `tip` being a fixed percentage, you set it in the `if` statement based on the cost of the meal.

Comment: If `user` is less than `.01` *and* greater than `5.99`?  You probably mean something more along the lines of `if 0 < user < 6`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  "I can't figure it out" is not a valid question here.

Comment: Do note that you've already conquered the main problem: how to ask whether the bill is within a given range.  Write more of those statements.  When you figure out just what pieces you can't put together, *then* you have a specific question for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a `tip` variable that you set based on meal price.

```
user = float(input("Please input the cost of the meal "))
tip = 0 # we'll overwrite this
if user > .01 and user < 5.99:
  tip = 0.1
elif user > 5.99 and user < 12:
  tip = 0.13
# etc, until...
else:
    # at this point user should be >= 25.01
    tip = 0.22
```

Then find the actual tip "price" and add it to total :

```
tip_price = user * tip
total += tip_price # note that you must still add tax and baseline price
```

Comment: While im sure all the options given by the community would have worked, I used yours due to me being a very novice programmer and your explanation was very logical for me to understand at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After this line you want to execute your logic:

`if user < .01 and user > 5.99:`

(I assume this was supposed to be total is between $0.01 and $5.99)
So an example would look like this:

```
if user > .01 and user <= 5.99:
    print("Total is: " + str((user*tax)*a))
elif user > 5.99 and user <= 12.00:
    print("Total is: " + str((user*tax)*b))
```

etc

Comment: Hey jhomr, thanks for taking the time to help me out. I tried your method but It would only calculate the user amount and tax. I tried to work around it to get the tip calculated as well but could not figure it out.

Comment: Hey there, the other answer that helped you had a portion I forgot. You would need to add `tax = #` before `print()` with # being the tax amount for that bracket. My apologies! You could also make sure tax goes back to a set value (like 0) by putting `tax = 0` **after** `print()`

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
import numpy as np
def price(x):
    if x<=0: return 0
    tax = 0.06
    a = np.array([0.01, 6, 12.01, 17.01, 25.01])
    b = np.array([10, 13, 16, 19, 22])/100
    tip = dict(zip(a, b)).get(a[(x>=a).sum()-1] , 0)
    return round(x * (1 + tax ) + tip,3)
```

for price 5, we have `5+(5*0.06) +0.1 = 5.4` for price=17, then `17+(17*0.06) +0.16=18.18` and for `30+(30*0.06) +0.22=32.02`:
Now calling our `price` function:

```
 price(5)
Out[745]: 5.4

price(17)
Out[746]: 18.18

price(30)
Out[747]: 32.02
```

Comment: Thank you Onyambu, while I am certain this would work I am unfortunately a very novice programmer and cannot use arrays yet for my school assignments. Thank you though!